# "requestOptions" is not defined

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I am trying to create a script in Google Sheets, so I can run an API to get the price of some Cryptocurrencies. I'm not familiar with scripts, and I truly thought it could be easier to do it using some code that I found on the web. However, it does not work, it says that the "requestOptions" is not defined. Could you please take a look at my script below and give me some feedback about what can I do to make it work?
Thanks in advance,
Pete

```
function myFunction()
{
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    method: 'GET';
    uri: 'https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/quotes/latest&#8217';
    qs:
    {
        start: 1;
        limit: 5000;
        convert: 'USD'
    };
    headers = {
        'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY':'APIkey'
    }
    json: true;
    gzip: true
    var url = 'https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/quotes/latest?symbol=BTC';
    var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, requestOptions);
    var txt = result.getContentText();
    var d = JSON.parse(txt);
    sheet.getRange(1, 2).setValue(d.data.BTC.quote.USD.price)
}
```

Comment: There's nothing in the code named requestOptions, so why wouldn't it be undefined? Also your syntax is invalid.

Comment: @JaredSmith -> `var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, requestOptions);`

Comment: @gearsdigital yes, and that's the first time it's referenced, and that's why it causes the reference error.

Comment: You said "there's nothing in the code named requestOptions", which isn't true. Just thought you've overlooked that. nvm.